# Reload tableView with delegation

Tags: cocoa

I'm trying to avoid the use of notifications with delegation. I need to reload a tableView selecting a row on another tableView, but reloadData() is not working.

```
protocol GroupDelegate {
    func groupDidSelectRow(selectedRow: Int)
}

class GroupTableView: NSTableView, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSMenuDelegate {

    var groupDelegate:GroupDelegate?

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self        
        self.groupDelegate = TemplateTableView()
    }

    func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        groupDelegate?.groupDidSelectRow(selectedRow: self.selectedRow)
    }
}

class TemplateTableView: NSTableView, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, GroupDelegate {

    var groupSelectedRow = 0

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
    }

    func groupDidSelectRow(selectedRow: Int) {
        groupSelectedRow = selectedRow
        reloadData() // This line is not working
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not the only line that's not working. ;) The first thing that jumps out at me is that you're doing your object initialization (setting up `delegate`, `dataSource`, etc.) _inside the table's drawing routine_. This is (a) crazy and (b) completely misplaced. One of the side effects is that a new `TemplateTableView()` object will be created _everytime the `GroupTableView` gets drawn_. Start by cleaning up that mess, then see how things behave. Also, there's no reason to avoid mixing delegate and observer patterns; they're tools, use the combination that solves your problem.

Comment: @james-bucanek Ok, I understand. It looks like it's the same reason of the notifications problem's that I'm having. I'm adding addObserver method in draw method so the problem is the same. In NSViewController I add this code in viewDidLoad. But I can't find where to add it in NSTableView. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Object initialization should be in the class' `init` method. Initialization of view objects is a little bit special because `NSView` subclasses can be initialized using two different initializers: `init(frame:)` for programmatically created views or `init(coder:)` for views loaded from a nib file. Alternatively, if you know your view will _always_ be loaded from a nib, you can perform post-init setup in `awakFromNib()`. See [Creating Custom Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html)

Comment: Also, since this is kind of Object-Oriented-Programming 101, I'd recommend you get the [The Swift Programming Language](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4-0-3/id881256329?mt=11) book and make sure you read and understand the chapter on Initialization.